# merge-with merge: can this be simplified?

Tags: clojure

I have a list of maps, and one of the keys in the map is a key that may repeat. I'd like to dedup/merge the list. So for example:

```
(def data [{:id 1 :a 2 :b 3 :c 4} {:id 1 :c 5 :d 6} {:id 2 :a 100 :b 101 :c 102} {:id 2 :a 103 :d 104} {:id 2 :a 200 :f 201}])
```

And I'd like to end up with:

```
[{:id 1 :a 2 :b 3 :c 5 :d 6} {:id 2 :a 200 :b 101 :c 102 :d 104 :f 201}]
```

(I've phrased the question so that merge/merge-with works, but the truth is I don't really care what happens with overlapping values; the first in, or the last in, can win).

What I've got is:

```
(vals (apply merge-with merge (into #(hash-map (:id %) %) data)))
```

Which does work, but I'm wondering if there's a better, more consise, or elegant, way of doing this. Also I wonder about performance because I think `into` is doing a full copy of the sequence, and forcing the entire thing into memory (the original data was a lazy sequence).

Comment: Are there any sorting guarantees on `data`? Do we know that all maps with the same `:id` will appear together? (If you can't guarantee that, then this is *impossible* to do lazily!)

Comment: yes they will be contiguous. They're the result set of a database query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know for sure that maps with the same `:id` will always be contiguous, you can use `partition-by` to create subsequences of the data by id and merge those subsequences:

```
(map (partial apply merge) (partition-by :id data))
```

This will be lazy and last-in will win.

Comment: that's awesome. I have one additional ask: let's say a map has keys that overlap, but sometimes the value is nil (and I want to take the first (or last) non-nil value)? I can ask as a separate question if that makes more sense.

Comment: nm...`merge-with` can easily do this. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, `merge-with` with a merging function like `%(if (nil? %2) %1 %2)`.

Comment: That's fine if you never have `false` as a value; otherwise you should test for `nil` explicitly.